# Style Guides for ASCII Text Documents

Tags: documentation, formatting, styles

What is a good style guide for formatting documents, outlines and procedure descriptions using ASCII text only?

I am thinking of a set of rules for using capitalization, 'underlines" (with '-' or '=' on the line below), indentation, etc to help visually organize text into sections, subsections, etc.

Guide supported by vi would be especially nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) or [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) for formatting your plain-text documents. There is a [vim Markdown syntax plugin](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/) available, and it's widely used on Stack Overflow and GitHub:

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown

Answer (score 0):

Beside Markdown and [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) there exists also [**AsciiDoc**](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/index.html), which is more powerful than Markdown: There are f.ex. plugins that define how you can [write](http://code.google.com/p/asciidoc-aafigure-filter/) [diagrams](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/) [in](https://code.google.com/p/asciidoc-diag-filter/) ASCII Text.

AsciiDoc is less popular than Markdown, but after [Github supports now AsciiDoc too](http://asciidoctor.org/news/asciidoctor-announcement.html) it will get more popular.

All these three text formats also have vim plugins.